# Kokua Winter '16 Template - Close case does nothing

Tags: community

When I'm viewing a case in Kokua Winter '16 communities, when I click on the Close Case button, nothing happens. Does anyone know if this is a bug or a security setting I'm missing.

Comment: Inspect the browser console to see if any JS issues else i would log this as a case with support and see what  they say